# XID POST from third party

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-express-checkout, xid

I am trying to integrate payment gateway with Paypal express. the issue is the payment gateway sends post data from paypal express checkout back to a specific URL in our ExpressionEngine but does not contain the parameter XID which is required by ExpressionEngine secure formS as of version 2.7.x

is there a way to accept the incoming post from external website without disabling the settings:
$config['secure_form'] = 'n';

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must create a module and a module action. There are docs [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html#install). The key is to grant your action a CSRF exemption, like so:

```
ee()->db->insert('actions', array(
  'class' => 'Module_name' ,
  'method' => 'method_to_call',
  'csrf_exempt' => 1,
));
```

Look up the action_id in the exp_actions table for your newly created action. Your action can now be triggered via url without XID at http://yoursite.com/?ACT=XX, where XX is your action_id.

Comment: This is not working for SagePay Offsite module, still get "The action you have requested is invalid."